# postgres php not giving every column in result set

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql, pgadmin

i am having a product master table and various other tables containing properties of product,the query :

```
select p.description, category.value, colour.value, wood.value, brand.value, type.value, fabric.value, model.value from product_master p, category, colour, wood, brand, type, fabric, model where p.category_code=category.category_code and p.colour_code = colour.colour_code and p.wood_code = wood.wood_code and p.brand_code = brand.brand_code and p.type_code = type.type_code and p.fabric_code = fabric.fabric_code and p.model_code = model.model_code
```

is working fine in pgAdmin but in php it is giving only 2 columns, i am getting result back via AJAX

my php code is

```
<?php
// Connecting, selecting database
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=***** dbname=*** user=*** password=***")
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

// Performing SQL query
$query = ' select p.description, category.value, colour.value, wood.value, brand.value, type.value, fabric.value, model.value from product_master p, category, colour, wood, brand, type, fabric, model where p.category_code=category.category_code and p.colour_code = colour.colour_code and p.wood_code = wood.wood_code and p.brand_code = brand.brand_code and p.type_code = type.type_code and p.fabric_code = fabric.fabric_code and p.model_code = model.model_code ';
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());



echo pg_affected_rows($result) ;

echo "\n";

echo pg_num_fields($result);


// Printing results in HTML
echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

// Free resultset
pg_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Comment: For `select` clause you should use [pg_num_rows()](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pg-num-rows.php) instead of pg_affected_rows()

Comment: @MarcioSimao agreed and that you for pointing that out but unfortunately thats not my primary concern

Comment: I've writen a answer, please see if it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [pg_fetch_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php) incorrectly. You can't pass the second parameter as NULL because it indicates which line is being read.

Try this:

```
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";

    foreach ($line as $col_value) 
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";

    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
```